# comparing a vector with a scalar

Tags: r, if-statement, conditional-statements, conditional-formatting, stringr

I am trying to write a function that will compare two matrix or list base on some parameters define in work.
the first function check if x respect the differents contraints and the second function check is the answer one if better than the second.
since the function is_sol_feasible return a vector when i run the function i received the following warning message:
the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

So i am wondering if any of you can help me with it? Thank you in advance!!!

```
'''
        is_sol_feasible <- function(x) {
          sat_c1(x) & sat_c2(x) & sat_c3(x) 
        }

        is_sol_x_better_than_y <- function(x,y) {
          sol_x_better = FALSE
          if (!is_sol_feasible(x)){
            sol_x_better = FALSE
          } else if (is_sol_feasible(x) & !is_sol_feasible(y)){
            sol_x_better = TRUE
'    # il s'agit de choisir la solution minimale'
          } else if (f(x) < f(y)) {
            sol_x_better = TRUE
          }
          sol_x_better
        }
'''
```

Answer (score 0):

I was stock on a code a few hour ago, searching how to compare a scalar with a vector using if function. After multiple reflexion i find a solution using "any" in my code.

```
'''
        is_sol_x_better_than_y <- function(x,y) {
          sol_x_better = FALSE
          if (any(!is_sol_feasible(x))){
            sol_x_better = FALSE
          } else if (any(is_sol_feasible(x) & !is_sol_feasible(y))){
            sol_x_better = TRUE
 '   # il s'agit de choisir la solution minimale'
          } else if (f(x) < f(y)) {
            sol_x_better = TRUE
          }
          sol_x_better
        }
'''
```